# what kind of a double spend attack is a career attack?

Tags: doublespend, confirmations, attack

there is an article that name different type of double spent attach like  "Several variations of attacks could allow miners with bad intentions to double spend. Included are the Finney attack, race attack, 51% attack, career attack, and unconfirmed transaction attacks."
but I couldn't find anything on career attack. what is this type of attack?
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/doublespending.asp

Comment: Can you link to the article?

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/doublespending.asp

Answer (score 1):

It might be another name for a race attack

See https://www.europeworldnews.com/double-spend-or-double-spend-attack-on-bitcoin-myth-or-reality/

> Career attack
>
> The Race Attack is a type of duplicate spending that affects Bitcoin merchants or users who accept payments without confirmation. Basically this attack is that the attacker makes a payment to a merchant with some coins and at the same time carries out another transaction with these coins to send them to another address that he controls. By manipulating the commissions of both transactions (lowering the commission of the first and increasing the commission of the second), these types of attacks can be more likely to succeed. Especially when the mempool is overloaded and miners only prioritize transactions with higher fees.